# How handle multiple oauth providers for account linking with alexa?

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0, token, alexa-skills-kit

My objectif is to give the user options to choose between different accounts (Google/Facebook/..), I created a web page for login (authorization url) using Laravel Socialite but I don't have any idea about how to handler it to end with a successful account linking with all providers in the same time because the developer console contains feilds for authorization and token url for one provider only?

Comment: the authorization token & url in Alexa is not related to the login providers. The logic stays the same for one provider or many. You might want to read how socials login works as well as how account linking works.

Comment: I think the authorization token & url in Alexa is related to the login providers, because when a user sign in you send the oauth code and the state with the amazon redirect url and then they send that code to your token url to get the access token, isn't it?

Comment: It is not linked to the login providers but to your own authentication service that wrap your login providers. Alexa is not linked to any provider but to the developer's logic: https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/account-linking/configure-authorization-code-grant.html